# Problema com submit do formulario

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Estou tendo problema ao tentar fazer um submit de um formulário quando meu objeto está nulo, pois ele não é obrigatório. Porem não é possível salvar com ele nulo.

```
/// Model
public class Atividade {
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "É necessário informar uma descrição.")]
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cliente")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente{ get; set; }
}

public class Cliente : BaseEntity
{
    [Display(Name = "Razão Social")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "É necessário informar a Razão Social.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Existe um limite de 100 caracteres.")]
    public virtual string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome Fantasia*")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "É necessário informar o Nome Fantasia.")]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Existe um limite de 150 caracteres.")]
    public virtual string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo*")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "É necessário informar Tipo de Pessoa.")]
    public virtual ETipoPessoa ETipoPessoa { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CPF/CNPJ")]
    public virtual string CpfCnpj { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Situação")]
    public virtual Cliente_Situacao Cliente_Situacao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Classe")]
    public virtual Cliente_Classe Cliente_Classe { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente ResponsavelLegal { get; set; }


    public Cliente()
    {
        DataCadastro = DataCadastro == new DateTime() ? DateTime.Now : DataCadastro;
    }
}

/// Mapping
public AtividadeMap : ClassMap<Atividade>{
    public AtividadeMap(){
         Id(x => x.Id);

         Map(x => x.Descricao);
         References(x => x.Cliente).Nullable;

         Table("Atividade");
    }
}

/// Controller
public void Salvar(Atividade modelo){...}

/// View
@using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "Atividade", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cliente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Cliente.Id, new List<SelectListItem>(), "Nenhum", new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "getOportunidade(this);" })
        <small>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cliente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions" align="right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-success " > <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Salvar</button>
    </div>
}
```

Então percebo que o HTML gerado pelo razor ficou assim:

```
 <select class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" 
data-val-number="O campo Id deve ser um número." data-val-required="O campo Id é obrigatório." 
id="Cliente_Id" name="Cliente.Id" onchange="getOportunidade(this);"
aria-describedby="Cliente_Id-error" aria-invalid="true">
<option value="null">Nenhum</option>
<option value="31">Édipo A.</option>
<option value="6">João J.</option>
<option value="30">Rodrigo S.</option></select>
```

Ao pressionar o botão salvar, o meu DropDownListFor() é focado. Apenas quando selecionado um Cliente o modelo é enviado para o servidor... Alguém sabe o que devo fazer para que esse campo possa ser salvo com valor null?

Comment: ja foi no banco de dados e setou nulo no campo lá  no banco? qual campo que deverá ser null? Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Ele não chega no servidor, consequentemente não salva no banco. O campo que deveria ser null é o campo 'Cliente'. Não tem mensagem de erro, apenas o campo do cliente fica focalizado, tipo obrigando a informar um valor para poder salvar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa informar que o campo não é obrigatório, altere sua classe para

```
public class Atividade {
    public long? Id { get; set; }
    public Cliente Cliente{ get; set; }
}
```

o `?` permite que o campo seja nullable

Comment: Sim, porém o problema esta acontecendo no Cliente mas não consegui criar fazer: public Cliente? Cliente { get; set; }

Comment: Não, Cliente é um objeto e eles aceitam nulo. O que deve estar acontecendo é que sua base de dados não está aceitando o cliente ser nulo. você está usando entity? se sim, você está fazendo alguma configuração do modelo no banco? pq ao adicionar o `?` era para ter criado uma `migration` que iria permitir o cadastro nulo de Cliente.

Comment: Eu estou usando o NHibernate, atualizei a pergunta com meu mapeamento para que possa dar uma olhada...

Comment: Mas parece algum tipo de validação javascript feita pelo @Html.Dropdownlistfor()

Comment: O erro é apenas no front? vc está fazendo alguma validação no campo com `data annotation?` remova o `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` de cliente

Comment: Sim! Acontece no front. Ah e estou usando sim, Esqueci de mensionar, porem no campo cliente o unica data annotation que estou usando é [Display("Cliente")]

Comment: Favor, adicione sua classe `Cliente` na pergunta

Comment: Atualizei la com minha classe de cliente

Comment: onde fica o campo `id` do cliente?

Comment: Ele esta dentro do BaseEntity, cujo só contem la dentro a propriedade: public virtual long Id {get; set;}

Comment: Então é por isso que está sendo requerido o campo, esse campo `public virtual long Id {get; set;}` não permite `nullable`

Comment: Acabei de fazer mais um teste onde criei o HTML do dropdownlist sem o uso do 'Html Helper', simplismente declarei um <select> e valorizei ele. Então funcionou o Submit!  O problema esta aparentemente ao usar o 'Html.Helper Razor'. Será esta a unica solução?

Comment: Na verdade o problema não está em usar o `Html.Helper Razor` pois ele "entende" o que está sendo solicitado pelo modelo, a partir do momento que o campo id não aceita `nullable` ele irá criar a validação. Tente utilizar o `helper`, mas remova o  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`, removendo esse helper é para perder a validação `front-end`